# How to wire a CO2 sensor to an arduino card and show / save its data

Tags: arduino, sensors, calibration

I'm trying for the first time to use Arduino for a school project, but I don't know much about it, so I hope you could help me.
I bought a CO2 sensor and I want to wire it to a "ELEGOO MEGA 2560 r3" (claimed to work as an Arduino Uno) to read the values of the sensor. More specifically I will have this kit:

° https://www.amazon.fr/ELEGOO-D%C3%A9marrage-dUtilisation-D%C3%A9butants-Professionnels/dp/B01JD043XC/ref=sr_1_1?__mk_fr_FR=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&dchild=1&keywords=ELEGOO+Mega+2560+R3+Kit+de+D%C3%A9marrage+Ultime+Le+Plus+Complet+avec+Manuel+d%27Utilisation+Fran%C3%A7ais+pour+D%C3%A9butants+et+Professionnels+DIY+Compatible+avec+Arduino+IDE&qid=1613500133&s=computers&sr=1-1

And this sensor:

° https://www.winsen-sensor.com/d/files/infrared-gas-sensor/mh-z14a_co2-manual-v1_01.pdf

(° [https://wiki.dfrobot.com/Gravity__Analog_Infrared_CO2_Sensor_For_Arduino_SKU__SEN0219#target₆](https://wiki.dfrobot.com/Gravity__Analog_Infrared_CO2_Sensor_For_Arduino_SKU__SEN0219#target%E2%82%86)

° https://docs.rs-online.com/c20e/A700000006944474.pdf) → this is another sensor which seems the same but may not be the same.

I want to know if I have to purchase another component, or it will be okay to collect the data of the sensor. I saw it had 19 circle pads and 8 pads with a wire to connect them.

```
PIN      Description
Pad1/Pad15/Pad17/Pad23  Vin Voltage Input
Pad2/Pad3/Pad12/Pad16/Pad22 GND
Pad4/Pad21  AnalogOutput(0.4～2V)
Pad6/Pad26 PWM
Pad8/Pad20 HD(Zerocalibration,lowlevelformorethan7secondsvalid)
Pad7/Pad9 NC
Pad11/Pad14/Pad18/Pad24 UART（RXD）TTLLevelinput
Pad10/Pad13/Pad19/Pad25 UART（TXD）TTLLeveloutput
```

The GND is the Ground, but I don't really know the others and how to wire them to my "ELEGOO MEGA 2560 r3" to take the data after.

If found this link with someone explaining how he did, but I don't have the same board. https://www.hackster.io/kritch83/getting-started-with-the-mh-z14a-co2-detector-e96234

" For the physical hookups we will use four wires: power, ground, RX, & TX and those are pads 19, 18, 17, & 16 but many are redundant. Connect as follows to your board:

```
5v DC -----> Pad 17
Ground ---> Pad 16
TX ----------> Pad 18
RX ----------> Pad 19"
```

I think I just have to use the same, but I don't know where to put them in my board.

For the code I want to print the value of CO2 in the air each x seconds and save the times and values in a file to create a graph after using python (I know how to code python but not Arduino). I saw this code on the tutorial I linked before.

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>  // for OTA, Blynk, & restart command
#include <BlynkSimpleEsp8266.h>  // for blynk
#include <ESP8266mDNS.h>  // for OTA
#include <WiFiUdp.h>  // for OTA
#include <ArduinoOTA.h>  // for OTA

char auth[] = "token";
char ssid[] = "IoT";
char pass[] = "password";

byte cmd[9] = {0xFF, 0x01, 0x86, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x79};  // get gas command
byte cmdCal[9] = {0xFF, 0x01, 0x87, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x78};  // calibrate command
char response[9];  // holds the recieved data

int CO2ppm = 0;

unsigned long warmingTimer = 0;
unsigned long timer1 = 0;

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);  // Setup a serial connection with the sensor

    Blynk.begin(auth, ssid, pass);

    wifi_station_set_hostname("ESP-CO2 Monitor");  // network device hostname
    ArduinoOTA.setHostname("ESP-CO2 Monitor");  // for OTA
    ArduinoOTA.begin();  // for OTA

    warmingTimer = millis();  // initilize warmup timer
}

void loop()
{
    Blynk.run();
    ArduinoOTA.handle(); // for OTA

    while (millis() - warmingTimer < 310000)
    {
        Blynk.run();
        ArduinoOTA.handle();  // for OTA

        if (millis() - timer1 > 1000)
        {
            Blynk.virtualWrite(V2, (310000 - (millis() - warmingTimer)) / 1000);  // counts down till the sensor is ready
            timer1 = millis();
        }
    }

    if (millis() - timer1 > 15000)  // runs every 15 sec
    {
        getReadings();
        maint();
        timer1 = millis();
    }

} // loop

void getReadings()
{
    while (Serial.available())  // this clears out any garbage in the RX buffer
    {
        int garbage = Serial.read();
    }

    Serial.write(cmd, 9);  // Sent out read command to the sensor
    Serial.flush();  // this pauses the sketch and waits for the TX buffer to send all its data to the sensor

    while (!Serial.available())  // this pauses the sketch and waiting for the sensor responce
    {
        delay(0);
    }

    Serial.readBytes(response, 9);  // once data is avilable, it reads it to a variable
    int responseHigh = (int)response[2];
    int responseLow = (int)response[3];
    CO2ppm = (256 * responseHigh) + responseLow;

    Blynk.virtualWrite(V0, CO2ppm);
}

void calibrate()
{
    Serial.write(cmdCal, 9);
    delay(3000);
}

void maint()
{
    int rssi = wifi_station_get_rssi();
    Blynk.virtualWrite(V12, rssi);
}

BLYNK_WRITE(V10)
{
    byte cali = param.asInt();

    if (cali)
    {
        calibrate();
    }
}

BLYNK_WRITE(V11) // restart chip
{
    byte reset = param.asInt();

    if (reset)
    {
        ESP.restart();
    }
}
```

I don't understand it all, what means "AOT" ? Furthermore, I found that website https://arrayofthings.github.io/, but I don't really understand why I need this to read the value of a sensor? I have the same issue with "Blinks" or "ArduinoOTA" (https://blynk.io/ ?). I guess it is to have a cool app, but it's a bit too much I think, I just have to display (in the terminal or on a screen as there's a screen in the box, but I may not be able to use a screen while I even can't figure how to wire my sensor to my board) and save data and then have them in a text file for example to use it with Python and create a graph, I don't need an app or anything like that.

I also need to calibrate it and if I understand well I just have to ask the sensor to do it by himself by sending this weir command? "0xFF, 0x01, 0x87, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x78" like that "Serial.write(cmdCal, 9);"?

I don't really understand this code, as I never used Arduino it seems a little complicated to me, could someone help me to understand it or help me to simplify it to just have 2 commands, one that print the value each seconds (I may be able to save it by copy and paste it after in a text file but if the code do it that's better) and calibrate?

I'm sorry for all this questions, I'm a beginner in Arduino, so I hope someone will help me :)

Have a good day, hinzelin

Answer (score 0):

```
Serial.begin(9600);
```

This command instructs Arduino Serial interface to setup communication with 9600bps baud rate. This is a prerequisite for the subsequent Serial commands Serial.Print. If you have connected your Arduino with a PC, you can see them on a terminal emulator.

This is the idea of calibration. Based on the graph that the manufacturer has provided, you can see that the output from the Sensor is 0.4v when there is no CO2. Even though it is the specified output this value can vary, as an example it can be 0.35v or 0.43v with 0 CO2. The manufacturer recommends to turn on the sensor in a 0 CO2 environment periodically, and adjust the voltage or the ADC value in your code in a way that it correctly represents the 0 value.

Comment: Thank you, it helps me a lot to understand!

As this is a school project I can't provide this sensor a 0 CO2 environment, do you think putting it outdoor, where the value of CO2 is known (about 430ppm) will be okay to calibrate it? I would just have to change the formula to have 430 with the voltage it gives me outdoor? 

Also, do you know how to wire this sensor to the "ELEGOO MEGA 2560 r3", I'm new, and I really don't know much about this ^^ 


Thank you for your help!

Comment: @hinzelin If you are only interested about the increment of CO2 level, you can do it. But if you need the actual ppm value you will need a calibrated device to use as the reference. The link you have provided contains a sample code and it should work as it is. The Arduino board you use, it is equivalent to Arduino Mega 2560.

Comment: I'm really sorry, but I did more research, and it seems like I gave the wrong links, it's write MH-Z14A on the component and I sent another component document because they look the same. The correct document must be this one: https://www.winsen-sensor.com/d/files/infrared-gas-sensor/mh-z14a_co2-manual-v1_01.pdf

But there's no code or instructions for the calibration and the wiring, so I found this: https://www.hackster.io/kritch83/getting-started-with-the-mh-z14a-co2-detector-e96234 But I don't really understand how it works, I'm going to update my post to fix all my mistakes.

Comment: I changed it all to fit the right sensor, I'm really sorry for that, hope you could help me on the new one.